# how to duplicate an object(in this case a array list) then clear just one of them

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 objects that contain an ArrayList and I want to perform the following steps:

1. Make a copy of the first object (because there is some useful data in it)
2. Clear the ArrayList in the second object
3. Add 1 element from the ArrayList of the first object to the ArrayList of the second object

   ```
   obj1.arraylist.add("f");
   obj2=obj1;
   obj2.arrarylist.clear;
   obj2.arraylist.add(obj1.arraylist.get(0));
   ```

I receive this error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: `obj2=obj1;` - you don't have two objects, you have two references to the same object

Comment: so how do i copy that obj to other?

Comment: First off, `obj2 = obj1` in Java means `obj2` will be exactly the same object as `obj1`. Second, your `obj1.arraylist` is empty at the time you're calling `get(0)` on it. Third, please post actual code. See [mcve].

Comment: its not empty i just forgot to write it here.i edit it

Comment: @roninshahi make a copy constructor, and then write `SomeClass obj2 = new SomeClass(obj1);`

Comment: You can create a constructor on you class that receives another object of the same class and copy their property values, or you can use a Kotlin map extension that copies the content from one to the other.

Comment: @eran isnt another way without using constructor?

Comment: You can write `SomeClass obj2 = new SomeClass(); obj2.arraylist = new ArrayList<>(ob1.arraylist);` but it's better to use a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a lot of other data in obj1 so constructor wasn't an option.so I used clone() and it worked.

```
OBJ obj1=new OBJ();
 obj1.arraylist.add("f");
 .
 .
//add some data to obj1 like 
OBJ obj2=new OBJ();
obj2=(OBJ)obj1.clone();
obj2.arrarylist=new Arraylist<OBJ>();
obj2.arraylist.add(obj1.arraylist.get(0));
```

and i just add a clone implements

```
  public class OBJ implements Cloneable{
 ...
 public Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    return super.clone();
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to "copy" the array list you can use the `clone()` method:

```
obj1.arraylist.add("f");
obj2.arraylist=obj1.arraylist.clone();
obj1.arraylist.clear();
```

If you also want to "copy" the rest of the object I'd suggest overriding Object's `clone()` method:

```
@Override
public SomeClass clone() {
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
    someClass.arraylist = this.arraylist.clone();
    someClass.someInt = this.someInt;
    ...
}
```

and then using the method to clone the class into another object:

```
SomeClass obj2 = obj1.clone();
```

You have to do this to actually "copy" objects because using the `=` operator only copies the reference.

Comment: Avoid clone. Use a copy constructor instead.

Comment: Clone method is not inherently bad.